# How do I activate regex search in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

This could be an embarassingly easy quesiton but If I search the following using the **find dialogue** of VS2010 with `\{.*?\}` I don't find anything even though it should find `{ return Stock ==5;}`

```
    internal bool IsUnableToBeSet //{}
    {
        get { return Stock == 5; }
    }
```

if I search this in NotePad++ it works.  What am I doing wrong in the VS2010 environment?
(I've unchecked all options except for "Use Regular expressions" )

[EDIT]

I've just read the [coding horror site](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/07/the-visual-studio-ide-and-regular-expressions.html) for VS2005 but is this still the case and can I convert the expressions easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2010 still has the custom regex syntax, but VS2012 has switched to the standard syntax.  For VS2010, the query you want would be

```
\{.@\}
```

Comment: cool. Thanks.  Is there a tool to convert standard to VS2010 or do you just go through the MSDN site and "figure it out"?

Comment: I don't know of any conversion tool, but the black triangle to the right of the "Find what:" textbox can come in handy.